# Launching a windows metro app programmatically

Tags: c#, deployment, windows-8, functional-testing

I am new to testing. I have been asked to perform functional testing for a windows metro style application. Is there any way of launching/deploying/re deploying a windows metro application programmatically using C# in a local machine environment?

Also I would like to know if a windows metro app in C# language is considered native or hybrid?

Comment: Duplicate of [IApplicationActivationManager::ActivateApplication in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12925748/iapplicationactivationmanageractivateapplication-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

Instantiate the activation manager and call [`IApplicationActivationManager::ActivateInstance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh706902.aspx).  You can find out all about how to do this in ["Automating the testing of Windows 8 apps"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsappdev/archive/2012/09/04/automating-the-testing-of-windows-8-apps.aspx) (that article includes a complete sample).

Comment: Thank you, but the code provided in the link is in C++, can I get something in C#?