# How do I launch a Windows Store application programmatically?

Tags: c++, xaml, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I just built one of the project templates Visual Studio 2012 offers (the 'Split App (XAML)' template accessible via Templates -> Other Languages -> Visual C# -> Windows Store in the 'New Project' dialog).

I can execute the application from Visual Studio 2012, and I can launch it from the Windows 8 start screen - but if I attempt to launch the generated executable directly (e.g. via the Windows explorer or from a command shell), a full-screen error message is printed saying "This app can't run on your PC".

Looking at a running instance of the application via Process Explorer shows that it a) just links against the .NET runtime MSCOREE.DLL and b) it gets invoked with a command line like this:

```
"[..] \bin\Debug\AppX\WindowsStoreSample.exe" -ServerName:App.AppXgsxd2athqtr03f55we0938hcn632we3k.mca
```

My actual question is: what's the correct way to launch this kind of application programmatically? Would I use plain `CreateProcess` and then try to assemble a command line like shown above? If so, how could I determine the correct `-ServerName` argument? Or is there some other way to launch such applications?

Comment: If anybody knows the proper term for these 'full screen' applications which were introduced with Windows 8, please let me know so that I can update the title of the question accordingly.

Comment: You mean Metro Application?

Comment: @AdamTester: I think so, yes. The ones which run full-screen and use the new tiled GUI.

Comment: Yah they are call Metro apps

Comment: They are not called Metro apps.

Comment: I think I found the solution myself now, just posted an answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [IApplicationActivationManager::ActivateApplication in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12925748/iapplicationactivationmanageractivateapplication-in-c)

Comment: They are called [Windows Store Apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh974576.aspx). "Metro" was the old (code) name for Windows 8.

Comment: Aaaand now (2016) they are called Universal Windows Platform (UWP) apps, at least in their Windows 10 incarnation. Seriously, as often as the official name changes, I would recommend to at least *also* call them Metro apps everywhere - if only for better searchability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way to launch Windows Store apps is to use the [`IApplicationActivationManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh706902(v=vs.85).aspx) interface. This is also what Visual Studio itself uses for launching the application. All methods on the interface have a `DWORD` out parameter which gets you the PID of the newly launched process.