# How to enumerate the installed StoreApps and their ID in Windows 8 and 10

Tags: c++, windows, powershell, app-store

What I want to get is the AppUserModelId of all installed StoreApp applications, so that I can pass it to `IApplicationActivationManager->ActivateApplication`.

In Windows 8 it was stored in the Registry, but in Windows 10 it is not anymore.

There are a lot of questions about this in internet but even after days of searching I could not find a satisfying solution.

What I have so far is the following:

1. I create an instance of `IPackageManager`,
2. I call `FindPackagesByUserSecurityId()` with the SID of the current user,
3. I iterate through the returned collection
4. I get an `IPackage` interface
5. From that I get an `IPackageId` interface,
6. Then I call `IPackageId->get_FamilyName()`

With that I have for example on Windows 10 for the Windows Calculator the string "`Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_8wekyb3d8bbwe`".

When I append to this string an "`!App`" I have the complete AppUserModelId to start the Windows Calculator: "**`Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App`**"

But not all applications use an "`!App`" behind the FamilyName.
For example Spartan uses the AppUserModelId
"**`Microsoft.Windows.Spartan_cw5n1h2txyewy!Microsoft.Spartan.Spartan`**" which does not end with "`!App`". And when I replace "`!Microsoft.Spartan.Spartan`" with "`!App`" it will not start -> "This app does not support the contract specified".

So my question is where do I get the last missing part from?

I found a PowerShell code in internet (http://poshcode.org/5702) that seems to do something very similar:

```
Get-AppXPackage $PackageName -pv Package |
    Get-AppxPackageManifest | % {
        foreach($Application in $_.Package.Applications.Application) {
            if($Application.Id -like $AppId) {
                if($Protocol -and !($Application.Extensions.Extension.Protocol.Name | ? { ($_ + "://") -match (($Protocol -replace '\*','.*') + "(://)?") })) {
                    continue
                }

                [PSCustomObject]@{
                    # Notice the secret magic property:
                    PSTypeName = "Microsoft.Windows.Appx.Application"
                    AppUserModelId = $Package.PackageFamilyName + "!" + $Application.Id
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I really don't understand this cryptic PowerShell stuff, but one line seems interesting to me:

```
foreach($Application in $_.Package.Applications.Application)
```

This seems to enumerate Applications in a Package.

A comment in the same PowerShell code says:

```
# The full AppUserModelId is composed of the package name, 
the publisher id, and the app id, such as
Microsoft.ZuneMusic_8wekyb3d8bbwe!Microsoft.ZuneMusic
```

so what is missing is the `$Application.Id`.

If I could get an `IAppInfo` interface anyhow I could call `IAppInfo->get_Id()` and I would be ready.

But I don't know how to get this from an `IPackage` in C++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Incredible that nobody has an idea!
This shows how Microsoft makes us life hard.
Such a universal task like enumerating the installed StoreApps with their AppUserModelId requires a cientific research department.

I finally came to a solution that works perfectly on Windows 8 and Windows 10. But a lot of code is required.

It seems that Windows does not hold the Application ID's in memory and there is no API to determine them directly. I studied all header files in the Windows 10 SDK and could not find a corresponding interface useful for that task.

But I found out how to get them. I continue after the 6 steps in my question:

7. call `IPackage->get_InstalledLocation()` which returns an `IStorageFolder`.
8. QueryInterface for `IStorageItem`
9. call `IStorageItem->get_Path()`

Now you have the path were the App is installed. Windows 10 uses two base folders:

- C:\Program Files\WindowsApps
- C:\Windows\SystemApps

and several others like

- C:\Windows\vpnplugins
- C:\Windows\devicesflow
- C:\Windows\MicracastView
- C:\Windows\PrintDialog
- C:\Windows\PrintDialog3D
- C:\Windows\WinStore

In the returned folder path you will find a file "`AppxManifest.xml`".
This file looks like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Package xmlns=".....">
    ......
    ......
    <Applications>
        <Application Id="microsoft.windowslive.mail" Executable="HxMail.exe" EntryPoint="Executable">
        ......
        ......
        </Application>
        <Application Id="microsoft.windowslive.calendar" Executable="HxCalendarAppImm.exe" EntryPoint="Executable">
        ......
        ......
        </Application>
    </Applications>
</Package>
```

And voilà, there they are. This package has two application ID's: "`microsoft.windowslive.mail`" and "`microsoft.windowslive.calendar`".

Then you take the package's FamilyName from step 6 append an "!" and append this ID and you are done.

This package can be started with `IApplicationActivationManager->ActivateApplication()` using one of the  AppUserModelId's:

- "`microsoft.windowscommunicationsapps_8wekyb3d8bbwe!microsoft.windowslive.calendar`"
- "`microsoft.windowscommunicationsapps_8wekyb3d8bbwe!microsoft.windowslive.mail`"

Comment: This relies on undocumented behavior. It's not recommended or advised. See my comment below for the solution using public (documented and supported) APIs

Comment: I did not try your code. But MSDN says that GetPackageApplicationIds()  requires Windows 8.1. For me a code is useless if it does not work also on Windows 8.0.

Answer (score 1):

Use PackageManager APIs to enumerate packages and GetPackageApplicationIds to enumerate applications in a package e.g. pseudo-code

```
FOREACH p IN PackageManager.FindPackagesForUserWithPackageTypes(null,
PackageType_Main|PackageType_Optional)
{
    PACKAGE_INFO_REFERENCE pir
    OpenPackageInfoByFullName(p.Id.FullName, 0, &pir)
    UINT32 n=0
    GetPackageApplicationIds(pir, &n, null, null)
    BYTE* buffer = new BYTE[n]
    UINT32 count=0
    GetPackageApplicationIds(pir, &n, buffer, &count)
    ClosePackageInfo(pir)
    PCWSTR * applicationUserModelIds = reinterpret_cast<PCWSTR*>(buffer);
    FOR (i=0; i<count; ++i)
    {
        PCWSTR applicationUserModelId = applicationUserModelIds[i]
    }
    delete [] buffer
}
```

See GetPackageApplicationIds() on MSDN for more details including working sample code
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn270603(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I did not try this code. But MSDN says that GetPackageApplicationIds()  requires Windows 8.1. For me a code is useless if it does not work also on Windows 8.0.