# How to access camera on a Windows tablet with Firemonkey?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe8

Like I wrote in the title, I want to take pictures from a Windows tablet, but do not found how do it.

Firemonkey is supposed to allow the multi-platform development, but everything I found to take pictures is working only on Android and iOS.

The sample given by Embarcadero [here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Berlin/en/FMX.AccessCameraApp_Sample) does not works on Windows, it appears that Windows do not recognize the event `TakePhotoFromCameraAction1` because any button with this action does not appears on the form.

I also tried [this one](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/Taking_Pictures_Using_FireMonkey_Interfaces), and 2 others called `CameraComponent` and `WebcamExample`, I do not remember where I found them, but nothing works.

I thought to try to access directly to the Windows' Camera application, like as the first answer [here](http://codeverge.com/embarcadero.delphi.firemonkey/virtual-on-screen-touch-keyboar/1052682) for the touch keyboard, but I do not found the .exe.

I am using Delphi XE8, and the target platform is Win32. Can someone help me on it ?

The device is the Fieldbook K80 : logic-instrument.com/en/fieldbook-k80.php

Comment: That's because there is no still capture implemented for Windows using those actions

Comment: is this still the case for Delphi 11?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to use the Windows Camera, perhaps someone else may be interested. I execute a Windows command to launch the camera app thanks to the library Winapi.ShellAPI :

```
ShellExecute(0, 'OPEN', PChar('microsoft.windows.camera:'), '', '', 1);
```

Thanks to this post in C# : [Run Camera App of Windows 10 from Desktop Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37299685/run-camera-app-of-windows-10-from-desktop-application)

Comment: nice, can try it first from the command-line, on Win11 seems to work fine, e.g. start microsoft.windows.camera: