# How to get other application(calculator) bring to front in winforms via vb.net?

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms

This might be a very common question but I cannot find a proper answer. 
Mark this duplicate with the original link if found any..

Say, I have a winform with a button.
And I want to open another application such as say a windows calculator.
so on Button Click, I added this.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
 Dim MyApp As System.Diagnostics.Process = New System.Diagnostics.Process
            MyApp.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\Windows\system32\calc.exe"
            MyApp.Start()


            Dim p() As Process = Process.GetProcessesByName("Calculator")
            If p.Count > 0 Then
                 /*Something like bring that calc to front*/
            Else
                MyApp.Start()
            End If
        End If
End Sub
```

Now I want something like to bring calc to the front if the calc is behind the winform.

If there is no calc open so it'll open new else it'll bring previous one to front.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12925748/iapplicationactivationmanageractivateapplication-in-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specifically for Calculator:

```
Public Declare Function BringWindowToTop Lib "user32" (ByVal HWnd As IntPtr) As Boolean

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim calc As Process = Process.GetProcesses.FirstOrDefault(Function(p) p.MainWindowTitle = "Calculator")
    If Not IsNothing(calc) Then
        BringWindowToTop(calc.MainWindowHandle)
    Else
        Process.Start("C:\Windows\system32\calc.exe")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Nope, its opening a new calc. Not bringing old one to top.

Comment: I believe because we are looking for "calc" when the process name in 10 at least appears to be calculator.

Comment: Right...I think Calculator is a special beast as the app that actually opens is not "calc.exe".  Try this with "notepad.exe" to see that it works.

Comment: Actually I wanted to open calc. :-|| @Idle_Mind

Comment: This won't work on Windows 10 onwards since running calc.exe opens CalculatorApp.exe